# How to configure the binary deserialization of DateTime bytes into DateTimeOffset?

Tags: c#, .net, serialization

We are changing the entity's timestamp to hold the timezone detail, hence planned to change the datatype of the timestamp field from datetime to datetimeoffset.

Now, How do we configure the Binary formatter to deserialize the existing data which are in Datetime Format to the model having DateTimeOffset?

The existing data is serialized in this below way.

```
 [Serializable]
    public class Entity
    {
        public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            BinaryFormatter _formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            Entity entity = new Entity() { Timestamp = DateTime.Now };
            byte[] result;
            using (MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                _formatter.Serialize(memStream, entity);
                result = memStream.ToArray();
                memStream.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You do not need the TimeZone.  DateTime is transfer as UTF.  Your DateTime is already in UTF,  When you parse a date using DateTime.Now it is stored as a number in your application in UTF.  When you then convert to a string myDate.ToString() the number is display with the machine timezone automatically.

Comment: hi @jdweng, we want to standardize and store the timezone detail for clarity

Comment: That is not recommended.   The standard convention is storage in UTF.  If you send data between two machines as an object (DateTime, not a string) it is automatically send as UTF.  Then you would be handling strings time different from object time which will create complications.